# Google Api Directions OVER_QUERY_LIMIT after one request

Tags: c#, json, directions

I'm using Google Maps Directions Api. I create simple app in C#/.NET core. I have code:

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient()) 
{
    var json = webClient.DownloadString(urlBuild);
    var googleApiDirections = GoogleApiDirections.FromJson(json);
}
```

And after only one request to url :

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=FROM&destination=TO&alternatives=true&key=APIKEY

I Get :

> OVER_QUERY_LIMIT..

I know about limits (2500 per day, 10 per second), about TRANSIT is like 4 request, but I requested only once.

Comment: This appears to be an issue specific to the API key you are using. I would check your account settings to be sure you have the correct access and appropriate query limit. There's no technical ambiguity here.

Comment: I found one thing.. In options I can set my requests per day. There is default value = 1. If I want to change this, I can choose between 0 and 1. thats insane

Comment: Have you enabled billing on your API project?

Comment: Should I? :D 
Okey then. I enabled billing with free year trial. I didn't know is here free frial. Thank a lot!